# Is it possible to load odbc dll directly without installing

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, azure-devops

I'm writing some integration my program which uses an ODBC dll on Visual Studio Online. The VSO provides Hosted Build Controllers so that I don't have to set up my own TFS server. However, to use the ODBC dll you normally have to install it for which the Hosted Build Controllers don't give me that permission.

Just wondering if it is possible to bypass the installation and load up the dll directly in some way?
Couldn't find some information about that anywhere.